# MVC: Passing Data from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How i can achieve passing data from controller to view without any action on view.

In my project ,

Event handler will raise an event in controller that will change the data of view in MVC.

I was searching for the answer and i come to know that
    *There should be some action on view* but i dont need it. 
     EventHandler will raise an event and that will pass data to view

Comment: What do you mean by "some action on the view"? Do you want to modify the view after it's been sent to the client?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this doesn't sound like you are using MVC architecture properly.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously want to fire server events on the client, don`t you?

To achieve this you need to use SignalR. You can find a very good article here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5

Comment: No buddy. How my controller can send data to view without any action on view(no button click). My RFID device will raise an event in controller and controller will send the RFID card no to view.(The card no will be displayed into the text box.) View will be waiting for data to be passed from controller.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly.There is no need of button click to call action in MVC.. If your view is waiting for data, then you need to tell the view that something has happened. So as @Bilyukov said, you can use SignalR, or implement some kind of polling to server, which can update the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**In your controller:**

```
 public ActionResult getID()
        {
            string qry = "SELECT COUNT(JobID) FROM tblDriverJob";
            IEnumerable<int> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(qry);
            int newFuelID = data.Single() + 1;
            string i = Convert.ToString(newFuelID);


            return new ContentResult { Content = i };

        }
```

and then in your **View**

```
   <div class="form-group ">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = @Html.Action("getID"), @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will fill this with the results from my Query.

NOTE: This will return a single value (count+1 to get new jobID) from my query. This design can also be used (with a little 'jigging' for a Drop down list (where I would return a **list** to the view).

Answer (score 0):

normally there are two ways for passing values from controller to view

1) you can store your values in ViewBag or in ViewData, this is preferable when your value is simple like a string, message,any id etc,

2) But if your data is of complex type like a search query result, then you should create a model with properties to store your multiple values, and then pass this model to the view while returning to view from controller's action (i.g. return (viewname, modelObject)), then you can access this model by defining the model at the top of your view like this @model yourmodelclassname, and then you can access each property of this model on your view by using the "Model" keyword.